# Double Double, toil and trouble

Tags: small-world-underground

I'm playing a Magic race AND I have picked up The Scepter of Avarice. If I put them both (and use the Magic Token as a second Scepter) in the same region do I get 4 coins? If I am the Shrooms and I put them both in a Mushroom Forest do I get 8? What if I control the Diamond Mines and they are in a Mushroom Forest as well? Is that 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no possibility of using 2 Scepter's of Avarice in the same area.**

From the [FAQ](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?th=22605&start=0):

> **Q.** May I use the Bag o'Many Things to duplicate the power of a Relic in a region where that Relic already is? For example, may I use the Bag on the Scepter of Avarice to quadruple my region's income?
>
> **A.** No. The power of a Relic cannot be duplicated in a region where that power already applies.